# Evaluation of post and pre increment in java

Tags: java, pre-increment

Evaluate the following Java expression, if k=3, l=5, and m=10:

```
++m + l - l + m + k++
```

Would the answer be:

```
    (++10) +5 -5 +10 +3

    =11 +5 -5 +10 +3

    =24
```

Or, would this be evaluated as:

```
11 +5 -5 +11 +3
```

which results to 25?

Comment: Run it and find out?

Comment: I did and the output comes as 25.

Comment: Where did that answer come from?

Comment: isn't it `11 + 5 - 5 + 10 +3` ?

Comment: So you are using Stack Overflow as a validation service for other 'popular sites'? And what are you going to use to validate Stack Overflow? Where does this process end? And the specific site you cited is notoriously riddled with errors: but even if it wasn't, it isn't the Java Language Specification, which is the only place you should look for information of this kind. At a pinch, the Oracle Java Tutorial. The page you cited has incorrect or dubious or obsolete answers to questions 2, 3 , 7, 10, 11, 14, 20, 26, 27, 33, 38, 40, 41, 48, 49, and some of the questions are downright meaningless.

Comment: I will definitely remember your advice the next time.....

Comment: I see you deleted the citation. Why? Trying to protect the guilty parties? Better to leave it here so we know what to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple proof: [IDEone](https://ideone.com/vXCpm9)  (or any local IDE or JDK)

or just use `jshell`:

[image]

or play computer/JVM (bit tricky, I know):

```
expression   k   l   m   expression-result
k = 3        3   ?   ?    3  (result not used)               
l = 5        3   5   ?    5  (")               
m = 10       3   5  10   10  (")              
++m          3   5  11   11  (after increment)
l            3   5  11    5
l            3   5  11    5
m            3   5  11   11
k++          4   5  11    3  (before increment)
11+5-5+11+3  4   5  11   25
```

Java Language Specification [15.7.1. Evaluate Left-Hand Operand First](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.1):

> The left-hand operand of a binary operator appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the right-hand operand is evaluated.

The give expression is equivalent to `((((++m) + l) - l) + m) + (k++)`. The left-hand operand of second addition is `((++m) + l) -l` and right-hand is `m`: left-hand one is evaluated resulting in `m` being incremented **before** the right-hand one (`m`) is evaluated.

Better (also) learn from the official source and not **only** from *popular sites*...
and
*obviously* you will **never** write such an expression - unless you want to confuse any other developer (and eventually yourself <sub>like the authors of that site :-)</sub>)